# how to add grid view side by side in web forms c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap-4, gridview

```
                <table>
                 <tr>
                  <td>
                  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
                  </asp:GridView>
                 </td>
                  <td>
                  <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server">
                  </asp:GridView>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
```

It is not working for me. Can someone please suggest a bootstrap class or anything that help? Thank you in advance

Comment: this format is not working for me

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Answer (score 0):

When we first start out, often we try and use a table layout and then dump things inside.

DON'T!!!

Just use a div, float it left. Put your grid or controls or whatever inside.

Want to then put more stuff to the right?

Drop in another div, float left.

So, if I wanted two grids, all side by side?

Then two divs, float left

you get this:

[image]

Or with markup, you get this:

[image]

And say you THEN want a combo box to the right of both?

drop in another div, float left again.

To start a new line, do this:

[image]

So, lets load up the two grids.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    public void LoadGrid()
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL =
            new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, HotelName, City, Province FROM tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName",
            new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4)))
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            GridView1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader();
            GridView1.DataBind();
            cmdSQL.Connection.Close();

            cmdSQL.CommandText = ("SELECT * FROM People ORDER BY FirstName");
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            GridView2.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader();
            GridView2.DataBind();

        }
    }
```

Output:

[image]

And really nice? lets add say a top title to each of the grids.

we have this markup now:

```
        <div style="float:left">
            <h2>Hotel List</h2>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover"></asp:GridView>
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;margin-left:25px">
            <h2>People Booked</h2>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover"  ></asp:GridView>
        </div>
```

and output now is

[image]

And doing the above in fact winds up with a "responsive" bootstrap page.

And you can add a "width" to each div, or to the grid if you want some sizing.

So, just remember:

I don't suggest the old "table" idea to get things to line up.

Drop a div, float left.

Now, you want a combo box, another grid (as per aobve)

Drop a div, float left.

Start a new line? div clear:both

Thus in 30 seconds, you can layout pages that take others 2 months of hard learning to layout. This simple trick? I been able to build any kind of web site I ever needed, and I don't even know web development.